# How to mock everything?

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, typemock

I understand how to mock interfaces or virtual method calls. But frameworks like TypeMock can mock everything in the framework. Which .NET mechanisms are used to provide such functions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typemock Isolator for example uses the CLR [profiler API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301725.aspx) to intercept .NET calls and change them during runtime:

[Quote](http://www.typemock.com/Docs/Unit_Test_Patterns-2_Mock_Types.php):

> Typemock Isolator uses an
>   aspect-oriented programming design
>   that creates a mock aspect.
>   Internally, it uses the .NET Framework
>   profiler API to monitor an
>   application's execution. When a method
>   is loaded by the CLR, Typemock
>   Isolator retrieves the IL and replaces
>   it with instrumented IL code. Typemock
>   Isolator does not change your original
>   IL code, it simply inserts new code
>   that calls the Typemock Isolator
>   framework and returns mocked values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you recommend a good article about this API?

Comment: [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300553.aspx) is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Mock Everything is one of the feature for Mock frameworks. Mock everything in short is to mock everything in a class, such as

- mock dependent objects
- non-virtual methods
- sealed classes
- static methods
- static classes
- non-public members
- non-public types

[JustMock](http://www.telerik.com/products/mocking.aspx) & [TypeMock](http://www.typemock.com/) both provide this feature.

You can actually look at source code of some open source mock frameworks such as Moq framework ,Easy Mock, Rhino Mocks etc.

Disclosure: Please note that link provided is of my own website