# Mock service without interfaces using rhino mocks

Tags: c#, unit-testing, wcf, rhino-mocks

Background
My application is consuming a WCF service via proxyies. I have to unit test my implementation, that it consume the service and processing are done correctly.

**Method to be Tested**

```
public class MyClass
{ 
 private ManagerServiceClientImpl myclient;

 public void MethodToBeTested();
 {
    var result = GetServiceData();
    if(result!=null)
       //some processing
 }
}

private MyObject GetServiceData()
{
    myclient = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ManagerServiceClientImpl>();
    if(myclient.ConnectToService() && myclient.MyServiceClient.IsConnected)
       return myclient.GetData();
    else
     return null;
}
```

**This is provided by external source, so I have no right to modify it**

```
public class ManagerServiceClientImpl
{
  public ServiceClient MyServiceClient { get; private set; }
  public bool ConnectToService()
}
```

**How would I mock the `ManagerServiceClientImpl` it doesn't have interface or methods are not marked as virtual**

What i tried so far.

```
[TestMethod]
public void IsServiceConnected_GetData()
{

  //Arrange
  ManagerServiceClientImpl clientImpl = 
               MockRepository.GenerateMock<ManagerServiceClientImpl>();

  ServiceLocator.Expect(x => x.GetInstance<ManagerServiceClientImpl>())
                .Return(clientImpl);

  var testData= new MyObject 
  {
            ID = "Test1",
            Name ="test",
  }

  //Act
  _myClass.MethodToBeTested();

  //Assert
  stubService.AssertWasCalled(h => h.SaveAllChanges());
}
```

*Note: Using Rhino.Mocks. Its my first time using Rhino mocks*

Comment: Wrap 3 rd party dependencies in an abstraction you control in your code and would be able to modify and mock. Avoid service locator anti-pattern which makes the code difficult to test as you have already discovered. This is a design issue.

Comment: Can u provide an example

Comment: First you need to clarify the method to be tested as your example is unclear.

Comment: I didn't understand you fully `MethodToBeTested();` is to be tested. The logic in the method is very small. If the service data is not in inventory add to the inventory. 

Im not sure is this what you asking for. pardon my enlgish
`

Comment: Check your small example and see if it even compiles. this is not a [mcve]. The code you have tried so far also refers to methods that are not even indicated in the method under test. You see what I mean right?

Comment: Take some time to improve and clarify the question less it be closed as being off-topic

Comment: Okay ,, i will provide a working sample

Comment: @Nkosi is right, wrap 'ManagerServiceClientImpl'  into an interface and inject interface into MyClass via the constructor. Back in your unit tests, mock up the interfce and test your MyClass. 
Another approach that I have used and definately prefer is to have a in-processes mock service of WCF's service contract...something like this:

'IWcfServiceContract mockDataService = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IWcfServiceContractt>();'
            'ServiceHostWrapper.Instance.SetupServiceHost(mockStaffMemberDataService, "mock endPointName", false);'

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680629/how-to-mock-everything/19266311#19266311

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use RhinoMocks (or Moq, or any other "constrained" mocking framework), the type you are mocking must support inheritance on the members you want to mock. This means it must either be an interface, or the members must be virtual/abstract.  Without that, these frameworks cannot do what they need to do to generate a proxy middle-man at runtime. For more details, see my blog post on how .NET mocking frameworks work under the hood: https://www.wrightfully.com/how-net-mocking-frameworks-work

What you *could* do is create methods in your own class that wrap the other service such that you could mock your methods and have them return whatever you need, completely bypassing the service.

Comment: In the article listed below you can see that it is possible to mock non virtual 3rd party libraries using "Uncontrained Frameworks" such as Telerik JustMock, Typemock Isolator, and Microsoft Fakes.

Answer (score 4):

As Amittai Shapira mentioned you can mock it without an interface by using unit testing frameworks that support it, i'm using Typemock Isolator and i created an example test for your code:

I've created an instance of MyClass and used a feature of Typemock to mock Non-Public methods to change the return value for GetServiceData

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var testData = new MyObject
    {
        ID = "Test1",
        Name = "test",
    };

    var realObj = new MyClass();
    Isolate.NonPublic.WhenCalled(realObj, "GetServiceData").WillReturn(testData);
    Isolate.NonPublic.WhenCalled(realObj, "SaveAllChanges").CallOriginal();

    realObj.MethodToBeTested();

    Isolate.Verify.NonPublic.WasCalled(realObj, "SaveAllChanges");
}
```

Comment: I dont have permission to add `typemock` to our project. Im restricted to use to rhino mock for now. Thanks for ur support.